# DataGridView Row BackColor

Tags: c#, datagridview

Nothing on a good search, so here goes the question.

I have a form with a datagridview that is populated via SQL query. There is a date column (stored as 'delay_in_hours' that I use to determine what to change the BackColor of the Row.

The problem is the backColor doesn't get set on the initial load of the form, only when the same event (loadSql) to load the form is triggered (like a button I have that says  to update / refresh form).

Here is the snippet:

```
public void loadSql(
  try
  {
  ...

    foreach (DataGridViewRow r in sqlDataGridView.Rows)
    {
        if (delay_in_hours >= Program._delay_warn3)
        {
            r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else if (delay_in_hours >= Program._delay_warn2)
        {
            r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange;
        }
        else if (delay_in_hours >= Program._delay_warn)
        {
            r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
    }

    sqlDataGridView.Refresh();
    sqlDataGridView.Update();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("loadsql Exception:" + ex.Message + " STACK: " + ex.StackTrace.ToString());
  }
```

I wasn't able to make a 'watch' for the backcolor. I set a watch item to the BackColor of the CellStyle, but all the item/values stayed unchanged as I iterated through the foreach, but when the foreach was completed, the rows had the backcolor even though the watch item never changed values.

Any ideas on what is causing this, or how can I debug the backColor so I determine why the colors are not set initially on the form when it loads?

SK

Comment: what value delay_in_hours has? try CellFormatting or CellPainting event

Comment: Here is the snippet for the delay part. I cast it as a double so I can do hour comparison since it is returned in seconds. ...Nevermind, I can't figure out how to post code in this reply...

Comment: put breakpoints on all r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor lines to check that this code is executed

Comment: yeah, did that, they do execute. Still scratching head on this. Problem was I don't know how to set a watch item to verify the color changed.

Answer (score 0):

I had luck with this using the RowPostPaint event.

There is an example here:

http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/08/13/painting-on-the-datagridview.aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting code. I'm trying to determine how to integrate. The current public method loadSql() is in another class. So if I use the RowPostPaint Event, I'm not quite sure how to use that event since the event would be private to the form and not available to the class that has loadSql().